# list string comparison

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say each letter in one of the list is called 'letter'. The problem I am having is when the string ==  letter for the first time in a particular list, I have to append a value to the new list. After that, if the string  == letter again in that particular list, I only need to update the value. So yeah, it would be really great if any of you experiences ones can help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension for this.

```
def num_common_char(lst, string):
    return [sublist.count(string) for sublist in lst]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some logic that states in words: "if not yet seen, add to list, otherwise increment". Or just be pythonic and follow @Tim's suggestion